# Github compare two commits with GraphQL?

Tags: github, github-api, github-graphql

Is it possible to `compare` with the Github Graph? Via their rest API, you can do something like:

`/repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head` (docs: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)

This works with SHA's, branches, tags, etc.

I'm most interested in comparing two SHA values but I can't find anything in their graph to support this.

Comment: You might be interested in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202547/how-to-compare-two-branches-in-github-with-graphql)